# popping ViewController into NavigationController

Tags: objective-c, storyboard

I have a navigation controller, root - `tabViewController`, and i have one more `ViewController`, it isn't in Navigation controller, there is in `ViewController` - button. 
How can i do on Clicking this button new `viewController` pops in current Navigation controller?

Comment: are you using storyboards? xibs? code?  show us what you have so far!

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ynfzui2z23prnx2/BrainyHouse.zip  that is my source

Comment: ..... i'm not downloading your app running it and debugging it. Its up to you to explain ... briefly ... how your trying to achieve it

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yibbppa97tzaqyl/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-03-27%2016.04.11.png    thats my storyBoard.  I want to click "Button" and pop to Settings view. And I can't

Comment: how do you get to the screen with the button then? that doesn't have a navbar either. How did you solve that one?

Comment: BHMainTabBarView *mainTabView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MainTabView"];
[mainTabView showSettings];

Comment: -(void) showSettings{

    BHSettingsView *SecondView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SettingsView"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:SecondView animated:YES];
}

Comment: ok so you know how to use `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` (NOTE: never add code to a comment, edit your question and place it in a code tag and EXPLAIN IT!!!). What is the issue? You have a tab bar controller then what? can you open the viewController on the bottom left with the button? is the issue you can't open that one or can't open another after that?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jw6axlzrw5zrkml/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202014-03-27%2016.31.47.png     i use PKRevealController for left menu, and i want to pop viewControllers by click link in left menu

Comment: I added an answer, next time explain what you are doing FULLY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long series of comments ... How you are using this app couldn't be more different than the original question.

You need to replace the `PKRevealController` front viewController when the button is clicked something like this:

```
[self.revealController setFrontViewController: newViewController];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have try to understend your question but i dont know if its that what you need:

1. Place a button in your firstViewController
2. move your mouse on that button and hold "ctrl" key
3. drag to the next view controller and choose push option

[image]

That's it!